How to send notification email from AWS to slack
Here is our requirement: if any user stops the running EC2 instance, creates the new instance, or terminates any instance, they have to send the notification to the Slack channel.
To test this scenario, we have created a new Slack channel. When I ran the curl command from local, it's sending the message to the Slack channel.
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXX/XXXXX/XXXXX

To test the same scenario tried from local machine it's working fine.
import requests
import os

# Define the data to send in the Slack message
data = {
    "text": "Hi, This is a test from Local"
}

# Get the Slack webhook URL from environment variables
webhook = os.environ.get("webhook_slack")

# Send the POST request to Slack
response = requests.post(webhook, json=data)

# Check and print the response status for debugging
print(f"Slack Response Status: {response.status_code}")
print(f"Slack Response Text: {response.text}")

But when we are trying it from Lambda it's not working.
AWS event bridge is going to call the Lambda function, this is working fine, However from Lambda it's not sending any notification to Slack.
import json
import os
import urllib3

SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL = os.environ['SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL']
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Log the entire event for debugging
    print("Received event:", json.dumps(event))
    
    # Extract details from EventBridge event
    detail = event.get("detail", {})
    instance_id = detail.get("instance-id")
    state = detail.get("state")
    region = event.get("region")
    
    # Log extracted details
    print(f"Instance ID: {instance_id}, State: {state}, Region: {region}")

    # Define message based on instance state
    if state == "running":
        message = f" EC2 Instance {instance_id} has been created and is now running in {region}."
    elif state == "stopped":
        message = f" EC2 Instance {instance_id} has been stopped in {region}."
    elif state == "terminated":
        message = f" EC2 Instance {instance_id} has been terminated in {region}."
    else:
        print("State does not match expected values. Exiting.")
        return  # Exit if the state is not relevant

    # Send notification to Slack
    slack_message = {
        "text": message
    }
    response = http.request(
        "POST",
        SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL,
        body=json.dumps(slack_message),
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    )

    # Log the HTTP response status and data for debugging
    print(f"Slack Response Status: {response.status}")
    print(f"Slack Response Data: {response.data}")

    if response.status != 200:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Request to Slack returned an error {response.status}, response is: {response.data}"
        )

    return {"status": "Notification sent successfully"}


Not sure where we are going wrong, provided Lambda role permission as EC2Readyonly access and Lambda execution role. even not able to find any error messages into lambda logs.
We do saved env values into lambda configurations

Lambda is probably timing out, either because it actually times out or e.g. because it is in VPC does not have internet access to send the message. Does the first log statement show up? If yes: what is the full log output from START to REPORT? If not: then your issue is not with your lambda to being with.

It's not running under VPC. in the logs it's not showing up.
in the logs START RequestId, END RequestId and REPORT RequestId, nothing else.

Check the application log level under Configuration > Monitoring and operation tools > Logging configuration

I have already verified on the same log path, which is under cloudwatch/log-groups
only below logs are available.
INIT_START Runtime Version: python:3.12.v38 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:7515e00d6763496e7a147ffa395ef5b0f0c1ffd6064130abb5ecde5a6d630e86
START RequestId: b4bd4021-97e3-4689-9f1b-bfa7091fbc06 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: b4bd4021-97e3-4689-9f1b-bfa7091fbc06
REPORT RequestId: b4bd4021-97e3-4689-9f1b-bfa7091fbc06 Duration: 2.25 ms Billed Duration: 3 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB Init Duration: 90.49 ms

Meaning not even the event logging works. Are you sure you are triggering the right lambda, in the right region, you saved the code, you do not have it saved to another version, etc. Try breaking the lambda fully, e.g. replace import with aosind and see if the next invocation fails.

Yes, it's triggering the right lambda function itself. I even tried testing the lambda manually, but same behavior; it didn't send any notifications to the Slack channel.

Did you do any of the things I did just recommend? Don't worry about the slack sending, worry about the logging first, something is fundamentally wrong with your lambda.
